# No output for N[Limit[Integrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n), {x, 0, Pi/2}], n -> Infinity]]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is my input below correct? I've received no response from Mathematica.

```
N[Limit[Integrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n), {x, 0, Pi/2}], n -> Infinity]]
```

Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Comment: The answer (output) should be $\pi/4$.

Comment: The result of the integral seems to be `Pi/4` for any `n`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Right. This is straightforward by letting $x=\pi/2-y$.

Comment: so problem solved ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks: I'm trying to learn to deal with such things by using Mathematica.

Comment: You are integrating a step function $H(x-\pi/4)$ from $ 0 $ to $ \pi/2. $ Use the squeeze theorem to squeeze the absolute of your integrand between one of the known analytic expansions of Heaviside step and you can calculate your integral by hand.

Comment: @gpap: thanks, but I usually compute such an integral without pen and paper. I only want to know how to handle with it when using Mathematica.

Comment: well, @Nasser's answer solves your problem then. If you wanted to PROVE that you have a step function you could do it with pen and paper, if you wanted to COMPUTE an accurate result, you can use `NIntegrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n) /. n -> 1000, {x, 0, Pi/2}]` that @Nasser gave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer, just will not fit in the comment.

Mathematica can't seem to be able to integrate `Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n` analytically. I tried using the formulas for `Sin[x]^n` and `Cos[x]^n` for odd `n` with the hope it will help. But still no luck. Using Wiki, the formulas are from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities)

```
mysin[x_,n_] := (2/(2^n)) Sum[(-1)^((n - 1)/2 - k) Binomial[n, k]*
     Sin[(n - 2 k) x], {k, 0, (n - 1)/2}];

mycos[x_,n_] := (2/(2^n)) Sum[Binomial[n, k]*Cos[(n - 2 k) x], {k, 0, (n - 1)/2}];

integrand = 
 Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0 && Element[x, Reals], 
  FullSimplify[mysin[x, n]/(mysin[x, n] + mycos[x, n])]];

res = ComplexExpand[integrand];
Integrate[res, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

Its been running for 30 minutes.

But doing numerical integration

```
Table[
 NIntegrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n), {x, 0, Pi/2}], {n, 0, 10}]

(*Out[1]= {0.785398, 0.785398, 0.785398, 0.785398, 0.785398, 0.785398, \
0.785398, 0.785398, 0.785398, 0.785398, 0.785398}*)
```

So may be you do not not need to do analytical integration after all? Are you sure this integrand can be integrated analytically?